# How to resolve these errors

Tags: java

I have a program that adds 2 numbers in Java and outputs the sum. (The numbers are input through keyboard). However, I have an error that I need help resolving. I'll explain the error after the code:

```
package com.sigma.java7;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Addition {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do {
        try {
           System.out.println("Enter A :");
           String numA = br.readLine();
           int a = Integer.parseInt(numA);
           break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Incorrect input. Please enter an integer.");
        }
    } while (true);
    do {
        try {
           System.out.println("Enter B :");
           String numB = br.readLine();
           int b = Integer.parseInt(numB);
           break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Incorrect input. Please enter an integer.");
        }
    } while (true);
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is: " +(a+b));
    br.close();
  }
}
```

In the line

```
"System.out.println("The sum of the numbers is: " +(a+b));"
```

I'm getting the errors: "a cannot be resolved to a variable and b cannot be resolved to a variable." WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you first do while loop add:

```
int a,b;
```

This will declare the variables to have scope outside of the loops so you can access them anywhere inside the method, instead of just a local loop. If you add this line of code, replace

```
int a  = Integer.parseInt(numA);
```

with:

```
a  = Integer.parseInt(numA);
```

and the same thing for b

Answer (score 4):

You have bad variable scope. When you define local variables it will work only work in a same block. ex.

```
{
    int i = 2;
    {
       int k = 4;
       // i can be accessed here.
    }
    // i can be accessed here.
    // k can not be accessed here.    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a *compile time error* caused by variable scope issues: a is defined inside the first try block, and is thus not visible outside that block.

As this has an assignment smell just a tip: move it to an outer scope and your problem will be solved..

Answer (score 0):

Define a and b in outer scope so that it is accessible when you print it out.